# ts-jest - Jest failed to parse a file -- jest.config.is configured correctly from what I can tell?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I know this has been asked a few times, but none of the solutions work for me. I am using `ts-jest` but receiving the following error when I run my tests:

```
    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

/Users/jamie/Desktop/dev/coral/src/__test__/LoginForm.test.tsx:19
        const loginSetup = (0, testUtils_1.render)(<react_redux_1.Provider store={store_1.default}>
                                                   ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I have been stuck on this for days and have ended up commenting out the test step in my build pipeline just to get it to build and deploy(!).

Here is the test file and the `jest.config.js` file:

`LoginForm.test.tsx`

```
import LoginForm from '@/pages/auth/login/components/LoginForm';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import store from '@/utils/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { act, cleanup, fireEvent, render, waitFor } from './testUtils';

const setup = () => {
    const loginSetup = render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <LoginForm />
        </Provider>
    );

    const loginForm = loginSetup.getByRole('form', { name: /login-form/i });
    const emailField = loginSetup.getByRole('textbox', { name: /email/i });
    const passwordField = loginSetup.getByPlaceholderText(/Password/i);
    const submitButton = loginSetup.getByRole('button', { name: /submit/i });

    return {
        loginSetup,
        loginForm,
        emailField,
        passwordField,
        submitButton,
        ...loginSetup
    };
};

const mockLogin = jest.fn();
const mockQueryParams = jest.fn();
const mockSocialLogin = jest.fn();

jest.mock('@/hooks/auth', () => ({
    useLogin: (): any => mockLogin,
    useSocialLogin: (): any => mockSocialLogin
}));

jest.mock('@/hooks/util', () => ({
    useQueryParam: (): any => mockQueryParams
}));

describe('Login form', () => {
    afterEach(cleanup);
    it('matches snapshot', async () => {
        const { asFragment } = setup();

        await waitFor(() => asFragment());
        expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

`jest.config.js`

```html
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/src'],
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/.*'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@/components(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components$1',
        '^@/pages(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/pages$1',
        '^@/hooks(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/hooks$1',
        '^@/utils(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils$1',
        '^@/styles(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/styles$1',
        '^@/context(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/context$1',
        '^@/lib(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/lib$1',
        '^@/slices(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/slices$1',
        '^@/provider(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/provider$1',
        '^@/theme(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/theme$1'
        // '\\.(scss|sass|css)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
    }
};
```

I'm at a loss as to why this doesn't work. I've followed several guides but it just doesn't run.

If anybody could help me solve and understand why this doesn't work I would really, really appreciate it!

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you wrapped other components in the `Provider` and had those test(s) succeed? Could you also show the `LoginForm.tsx`?